# why we use Concurrency Check Attribute in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am new to entity framework.Can any one explain why we use Concurrency Check attribute in  entity framework with example.In scenario we use this attribute.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 16):

It's a way to handle conflicts to database changes when multiple users are updating entities at the same time.  Adding the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute means that you are telling 
Entity Framework to use that property for detecting concurrency conflicts.  Entity Framework includes the property in `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s to the database.

For database tables that have many columns this can mean very large `WHERE` clauses, which can affect performance and require you to manage large amounts of state. For larger databases a row version strategy is preferred.

```cs
[Table("Accounts"]
public class Account
{
    public Account() {}
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string AccountName { get; set; } 
}
```

SQL Server will include `AccountName` in `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s to the database:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Accounts]
SET [AccountName] = @0
WHERE (([AccountId] = @1) AND ([AccountName] = @2))
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'Dick',@1=1,@2=N'Harry'
go
```

This returns no (zero) rows to the user because of the concurrency check.

Comment: What about the `Concurrency Mode` property that we set inside the EDMX designer for the columns corresponding to our entity? Is this attribute `[ConcurrencyCheck]` in your entity meets the same purpose? `Concurrency Mode` property is also used to deal with field level concurrency errors in entity framework.

Comment: Exactly!  The where clause will be updated to reflect the column and if different will throw DbUpdateConcurrencyException.  From the source code ConcurrencyMode is an enum.
namespace System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm 
 { 
     public enum ConcurrencyMode 
     { 
         None, 
         Fixed, 
     }