# How to prevent multiple users to update a record at the same time using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, linq, asp.net-core

I have below LINQ to update a record and in some cases it may be `IEnumerable` too.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(Int ID, decimal confirmQty)
{               
    using (var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // Need to Lock here whether single record or multiple records
            var invReduce = _context.Inventorys.Where(w=>w.id == ID).FirstOrDefault();
            invReduce.availQty -= confirmQty;

            Thread.Sleep(60000); // One Min
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            tran.Commit();

            // Need to Un-Lock here whether single record or multiple records
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Here, 1st user can query the data and should lock it to prevent 2nd user to querying same data. On 1st user's process completes, 2nd user query should automatically run.

**Update**: for example, for id:1, qty is 1000, first user requests to reduce qty by 100, also 2nd user sends requests for 100 to reduce at the same time and before 1st user's `SaveChanges()` takes effect. Final reduce qty should be 1000 - 100 - 100 = 800.

So, till the time 1st user's operation completes, 2nd user's query should be in the queue.

I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 code-first, PostgreSQL, no stored procedures.

How do I lock rows here?

Comment: Look for transactions in SQL

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, using transactions is not enough, you need to use serializable isolation level. But with this level you get deadlock errors when executing that code concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Try using transactions in your queries that have to be atomic (no operation can be executed on data affected by this operation).

Read [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-transaction/) for example.

Additionally, read about different locking levels, to prevent simultaneous updates, etc.

Comment: My requirement is that till the time 1st user's operation completes, 2nd user's select query should be in Que.

Comment: In transaction case, it stors or throws conflict error. But I need to go to same method's beginning point to read it again in case of conflict error. or wait until, 1st user's operation completes.

Comment: Best is to wait until 1st user's operation completes.

Comment: Well, it should queue the operation, did you actually tried this approach?

Comment: My method throwing ChangeConflictException. Let me try with BeginTransaction.

Comment: I just tried with Thread.Sleep(60000); before SaveChangesAsync(), and tried to access this method from two different browser. Both just simply executes, neither throws error nor wait for 1st operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Such locking schemes are known as pessimistic locks and are more prone to problems than the alternative of optimistic locking. Optimistic isn't actually a locking mechanism at all; it lets either user who has the same record try to make their edit. As part of the update the ORM passes all the previous values back to the dB and forms the query such that it compares every current table value with every previous value known by the orm (from the time the record was pulled). If any o he values have been changed by another user then the update fails and returns 0 records updates. At this point the orm can raise an exception to you indicating that someone else has edited the same record. You consume this exception and inform trhe user, perhaps giving them a choice of what to do:

- overwrite theirs with mine
- keep theirs and abandon mine
- merge with theirs

You've seen it when coding and committing your changes to source control, I'm sure :)

Of course, you have to write an interface to do this but it's usually the right thing to do because only the user can know what the data should be. If you're not offering merge then it can be a simple dialog box of "keep mine/keep theirs"

Your proposal to keep things in a queue and only apply edits sequentially doesn't make so much sense to me because the second edit is editing data the first user edited already; how do you know you'll end up with a valid state if you solve the concurrency problem programmatically? If you're just going to overwrite person1's changes with person2's then you don't need any concurrency control at all

I've touched on how an optimistic concurrency system works, but assuming you're using EF Core, the fine manual has a lot more to say:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Comment: In this method, I am trying to reduce sold qty at inventory table in a POS app so In this particular case, it is not necessary to inform 2nd user that 1 user had sold some qty and taking 2nd user confirmation again. So I would like to be in que and then proceed with latest reducing sold qty(confirmQty) on 1st user's SaveChanges().

Comment: I'n a case like that, I'd generally recommend then to go the transaction route if you have a clearly defined way of solving the problem programmatically. You can set a constraint on the database that it doesn't allow the quantity to go below zero and then when the database refuses your request to decrement the stock of 7 by 10 units, you can cancel the transaction and go back to the user who wants 10 with an update that only 7 are available. In this case you don't need a complicated queuing mechanism - just bang the database with the update requests and they will either work out or not

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the following raw update query:

```
UPDATE MyInv
SET qty = qty - @confirmQty
WHERE ID = @ID AND qty >=  @ConfirmQty
```

It prevents the concurrency issues you are facing in your code.

Note `qty >=  @ConfirmQty` it prevents setting the quantity below 0. You can check the affected rows, if it is 0 you can say there is not enough items to pull out the inventory.

Comment: I am sorry, I am using Code First Method.

Comment: @Ramesh, Did you know you can execute raw sql in Entity Framework code first?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, my method includes some other business logic too. So I cannot use Raw SQL in my case.

Comment: @Ramesh I'm pretty sure you can combine raw SQL with other business logic

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(Int ID, decimal confirmQty)
    {
        using(var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {

                var invReduce= _context.MyInv.Where(w => w.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
                inventoryReduce.qty -= confirmQty;
    // some long operation too goes here...
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                // log error if necessary
            }

            return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: My requirement is that till the time 1st user's operation completes, 2nd user's select query should be in Que.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add int Version in each base entity to check if his version is matching with the current version of each data.

```
class Inventory
{
      //properties
      public int Version {get; set;}
}
```

and every SaveChanges() will have these property

```
inventory.Version = inventory.Version + 1;
```

then if both of us will have a Version = 1, and one of us updated same field before the other, will cause error due to the Version increment.

Sample checking below

```
var inventory = context.Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Model.InventoryId);

 //check if inventory is not null if not continue
 if (inventory.Version != Model.Version)
 {
      //throw exception, DbContextConcurrencyIssue, error handling codes
 }
 else
 {
     //continue with process
 }
```

Any update will increment the version and will not match with the other users who have the previous Version

Answer (score 0):

you can `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute at the top of field of table to ensure conflict not happen.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611113/9076865)  and [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency)